# Soapui maven plugin ssl host parameter

Tags: maven, soapui

We have a set of soapui tests that are being run via a maven project using the soapui maven plugin which is run by a Jenkins job as well.

As we have various environments we pass a "host" parameter via the environment, from Jenkins to the Maven build.

There is a `<host>${HOST}</host>` element that allows us to configure the host. The problem is that the maven plugin seems to dislike when adding the protocol prefix inside the parameter value:

`<host>example.com</host>` Will work

`<host>https://example.com</host>` Won't work (java.net.UnknownHostException: https)

**So if I am not allowed to provide the protocol prefix, then I don't know how to tell the maven soapui plugin that the host is using ssl.**

Here is the configuration in the pom.xml that we are using:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/my-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                <host>${HOST}</host>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <soapuiProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>soapui.logroot</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/soapui-logs/</value>
                    </property>
                </soapuiProperties>
                <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/soapui-output</outputFolder>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>first-tests</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <testSuite>first-TestSuite</testSuite>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>second-tests</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <testSuite>second-TestSuite</testSuite>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
...
```

**Edited: Based in the answer by Bistro:**

Instead of using `<host>${HOST}</host>` I now use `<endpoint>${HOST}</endpoint>` it does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding an `<endpoint>` parameter. Someone in the SoapUI forum had a similar issue, but was able to resolve the connection issue by adding this parameter. He does mention that it causes another issue. But it's worth a shot. Here is the post [link](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3769&p=13184&hilit=maven%20plugin%20host#p13184)

Comment: No, it doesn't work as I explained in the question. The documentation says this: "host : Overrides the target host:port to be invoked by any TestRequests" I don't see any place where it says that it should include the protocol prefix. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you try adding an <endpoint> parameter. Someone in the SoapUI forum had a similar issue, but was able to resolve the connection issue by adding this parameter. He does mention that it causes another issue. But it's worth a shot. It also might be worth posting your question on the SoapUI forum as well. Here is the post [link](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3769&p=13184&hilit=maven+plugin+host&sid=63190545aff8565d0378a8157f552b27#p13184)

Comment: Can you update your answer and mention that I should use the <endpoint> parameter instead of host? That works (I am able to provide the protocol and it seems to be going through ssl), but I cannot accept the answer as it is written now.